# Running ASP.NET Core 2 on a linux server with Apache

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a web-hotel at www.unoeuro.com I'm already using it for a few different things, like to run a mediawiki, and so I chose the server that's set up for PHP. From what I understand they are using CloudLinux and apache for the server.
http://linux142.unoeuro.com/phpinfo.php

As I understand it asp.net core is cross-platform, and I've been using C# for close to ten years, so it's easier for me to whip a website up in ASP than it would be to shape a PHP cms to my needs.
That said I can't figure out how to deploy to the server.

I've read that I should add this to my 'PropertyGroup'.

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<SuppressDockerTargets>True</SuppressDockerTargets>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

And this to my 'ItemGroup'

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
```

And then run
"dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64"

Which I've done. This gives me a load of files and folders in
Website\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\linux-x64\

I've uploaded these to the server but I get a 403 error when I attempt to access the website through a browser.

Is it even possible to run asp.net core on this setup? And if so, how would I do it? What am I missing?

Comment: I am just using a template project, by the way, I haven't added anything else except these suggestions.

Comment: You are definitely trying to run before you can walk. There are so many things wrong with your approach here that it isn't really worth trying to address all the issues. It might be better to learn how to do this in a cleaner environment before attempting to set it up on your "web-hotel". [Download yourself compatible linux distro](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0-supported-os.md), install it on a VM and [get to grips with the basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/). Just copying things into an exposed web folder won't get you anywhere.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you :)